# WPF Aero theme standard styles

Tags: wpf, styles, aero

When using the Aero theme, are there resource names for styles that I can hook in to to achieve the same appearance as standard Win7 apps:

[image: control panel example]

In other words, are there already well-known style names for TextBlocks (and other controls) that would let me achieve a similar appearance to what is in the image above?

In XAML it would look something like this:

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource WindowsHeading}" />
```

Comment: I've taken a look at the SystemColors, SystemFonts, and SystemParameters classes - they looked promising but do not have the colors/sizes I need. They appear to be a smaller sub-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["Windows Vista User Experience Guidelines Aero Theme Aesthetics"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa511286)

That's AFAIK all there is.

Comment: I've tried a number of ways of using the text styles called out in that guide but nothing seems to work. Not too surprised - that guide doesn't look like a WPF-specific resource at all. Thanks though.